# Remove line from txt file if it endswith xyz

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a python code to check each line in a .txt file and delete that line if it ends with A/ or Z/. This is what I have written, please help me take it forward.

```
f = open('test.txt', 'r')
for line in f.readlines():
    if (line.endswith("A/") or line.endswith("Z/")):
        Remove that line in test.txt
```

Comment: You can't "remove" lines from a file, so better think of an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot write to the same file you are reading from. So write it to a new file and then rename the new file to old file.

Also `line` would end with `\n` or `\r\n`. So checking `line.endswith("A/")` would always fail. So better use regex based check

```
import re
import os
with open('test.txt', 'r') as in_file:
    with open('test2.txt', 'w') as out_file:
        for line in in_file.readlines():
            if re.search(r'[AZ]/[\r\n]+', line):
                continue
            out_file.write(line)

os.rename('test2.txt', 'test.txt')
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if you are happy with my answer

Comment: I don't know how to do that. I am new here. Could you please guide me?

Answer (score 1):

Get all lines. Open the same file in write and write lines that you need -

```
f = open('file.txt', 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
f = open('file.txt', 'w')
for line in lines:
    if not line.endswith(("A/", "Z/")):
        f.write(line)
f.close()
```

Comment: you can't write and read like this, also the `or` here should be an `and`.

Comment: You can. Why don't you try before down voting my answer.

Comment: You are right about `and` but saying that you can't write and read like this is wrong.

Comment: +1 for not using a regex.  `str.endswith` accepts a tuple of strings to test, so you could do `if not line.endswith(("A/", "Z/")) :`

Comment: What @MatthewStory (probably) alludes to is that opening a file *and never closing it* is potentially un-safe. You re-use `f` as the file handle for a next operation, so the handle to that open file is lost and you cannot close it anymore. So, your OS keeps it "open"; but apparently it does not mind having it subsequently overwritten by another one. Some OSes are not that careless. Use the more Pythonic `with`, and the indentation will show the file lifetime for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can first open the file and keep the lines in a list that dont end in  with `A/` and `Z/`:

```
keep = []
with open('test.txt') as in_file:
    for line in in_file:
        # store in temporary variable to not disrupt original line
        temp = line.rstrip() 
        if not temp.endswith('A/') and not temp.endswith('Z/'):
            keep.append(line)
```

Then you could write out the lines from this list to the same file afterwards:

```
with open('test.txt', 'w') as out:
    for line in keep:
        out.write(line)
```

**Note:** Since the lines in the files could carry `\r` oe `\n` characters at the end, you can strip these with [`str.rstrip()`](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/rstrip.html). This is needed since strings like `A/\n` will fail on `str.endswith('A/')`.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can't Just read and edit the same file when it is opened at the same time.
 Instead you can read it, store the content, modify the content and re write into same file without opening a new file or without opening the same file again.

```
import re
new_lines = []
with open('sample.txt', 'r+') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
     for i, line in enumerate(lines):
         if not re.search(r'[AZ]/[\r\n]+', line):
             new_lines.append(line)           # store the content 
    f.truncate(0)     # empty file
    f.seek(0)         
    for line in new_lines:
        f.write(line)   # write into same file
```